# `const_cast`, top-level const and lvalue-to-rvalue conversions

Tags: c++, standards, implicit-conversion, const-cast

Let's assume we have a simple piece of code,

```cpp
int main() {
  int x = 5;
  int* const y = &x;
  const_cast<int*>(y);
}
```

Is my assumption that a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happens inside the `const_cast` expression, to read the value of `y`, correct?

If it is... Would it then be correct to say that `const_cast` can *never* be used to cast away a top-level `const` qualifier, since it's removed implicitly during this lvalue-to-rvalue conversion?
And what about *adding* top-level const qualifiers? I see it's possible, but are we *really* adding a top level const when we do something like:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int* y = &x;
    const_cast<int* const>(y);
}
```

...this clearly won't add the top level const qualifier to `y`... and we could just do the same implicitly with an assignement to const pointer. So what is this needed for?

Comment: You do realize that `int* ptr = y;` is valid, no `const_cast` needed at all.

Comment: A variable is a variable. A variable has a type. This is type of the variable. And nothing never change. The type of a variable cannot change.

Comment: @fabian I realize that. I'm just asking a different question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it then be correct to say that const_cast can never be used to cast away a top-level const qualifier, since it's removed implicitly during this lvalue-to-rvalue conversion?

Informally, "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion" means something like "the value of the object is read".

`const_cast` only needs to do it when casting to a non-reference, so casting to a reference wouldn't peform it, I believe, so constness wouldn't be stripped automatically.

Also note that [prvalues of class and array types can be `const`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-2), unlike scalars.

> And what about adding top-level const qualifiers?

Sure, casting to a `const T &`. Remember that [expressions can't have reference types](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1), so `const_cast<const T &>(...)` returns a top-level const lvalue of type `const T`.

> are we really adding a top level const when we do something like: `const_cast<int* const>(y);`

No, not in this case. You have to cast to a reference.

Comment: So in `const_cast<int* const>(y);` the const should be stripped out implicitly because prvalues non class non reference types can’t have cv. Is that correct?

Comment: @SomeoneWithPassion Prvalues (and expressions in general) can't be references, you probably meant non-class non-array. Otherwise yes.

Comment: Woops, typo. That’s exactly what I meant. Thank you!